# JQuery - Onclick - Alert the amount of time elapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, global-variables

When a user presses the escape key, I would like to show an alert message, declaring the amount of time that has elapsed since they started typing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      var current_date = new Date();
      var time_end = current_date.getTime();
      alert(time_end - time_start);
    }});
  $(":input").click(function() {
     var date = new Date();
     var time_start = date.getTime();
  });
```

The problem is that because `time_start` is a local variable, defined in the `$(":input").click` function, I can't access it in the `$(document).keyup` method.

Unfortunately, I also can't make it a global variable by declaring it outside the function because I have the timer has to be started when a user clicks inside an input box.

According to W3Schools, time_start should be a global variable because I assigned the value `date.getTime()` to it.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First W3Schools is bad see http://www.w3fools.com/, Use Mozilla developer network instead, second you could use a localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the point in time when they start typing on a parent node of the input.
For example on the `<body />` element (there may be better places for this)

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", function(ev) {
    if (ev.which != 27) {
      return;
    }

    var startTime = $("body").data("startTime");
    if (typeof startTime != "object") {
      return;
    }

    alert(new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime());
  });

  $(":input").on("click", function() {
    $("body").data("startTime", new Date());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems more efficient than what I had too

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a check for `startTime` in the `keyup` event. So it won't throw an error if the ESC key is pressed before someone clicked in the `:input` field